# Transition functions of the the twisted tangent bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose we are on a complex manifold $M$ of dimension one.

I am trying to figure out what would be the transition functions of the following bundle

$$ TM \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_M} \mathcal{O}(-z)$$

where $z$ is a point on $M$ and $TM$ is the holomorphic tangent bundle on $M$. An easy way to think of this bundle is as the the sections of tge tangent bundle with coefficients functions of the structure sheaf which vanish at $z$.

I know that the transition function of $TM$ is just the Jacobian of the change of variables. However, I would I describe the transition functions of the bundle $ TM \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_M} \mathcal{O}(-z)$?

If $\overline{z}=f(z)$ my guess is that the transition function would be of the form $zf'(z)$

Comment: You should first start by specifying an open covering. Note that $\mathscr O(-z)$ is trivial off a neighborhood of $z$.

Comment: Good point. I imagine the trivial bundle would have transition functions just multiplication by 1. Thus on open sets intersecting in $z$ it seems like the transition functions should be mulitplication by $z$.

Comment: When you translate appropriately into local coordinates, yes, depending on the direction of your transition. Be careful with definitions. And then multiply by the jacobian for the tangent bundle.

Comment: You should describe the transition functions for $O(-z)$ and use that if $L,L'$ are line bundle with transitions functions $g_{ij}, h_{ij}$ then $L \otimes L'$ has transition functions $g_{ij}h_{ij}$. For example, for $M = \mathbb P^1$ the transitions functions for your bundle are just $g_{01} = (\frac{z_0}{z_1})^3$.